# Virtualbox: 'Please install kernel "header" files matching current kernel' despite current version installed

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I'm failing to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions on my guest OS fedora.

I installed `kernel-devel` and `kernel-headers` package which I assume should contain the required resources.

However, upon executing the Guest additions package, I get the error from the title.

Some info:

- Host system: Windows 10
- Fedora version: newest
- Guest additions version: newest

Comment: Please check that kernel-devel and kernel-headers are exists for currently running kernel: `rpm -qa|grep -E "(kernel-devel|kernel-headers)"|grep $(uname -r)`.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, it produces no output. What does that mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is strangely. Run `rpm -qa|grep kernel` instead. This command ensure that you have packages with pattern `kernel` in title. Please, show me output.

Comment: [Here you go](https://pastebin.com/hj8FdDvw). Can you tell me what that output means, please?

Comment: You sad that you installed `kernel-devel` and `kernel-headers`. So, we check that it's really true. In next step we need ensure that version of installed headers and develop facilities are match. So, please run `uname -r` and produce output.

Comment: `uname -r` returns `4.15.10-300.fc27.i686+PAE`. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: Can you paste logs `/var/log/vboxadd-*` and `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` to pastebin? I saw logs more close.

Comment: Sure: [`/vbox/log/vboxadd-*`](https://pastebin.com/1CaFWNuj). `/var/vbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` doesn't exist.

Comment: Upon close inspection - it seems to me the headers I've installed are missing the `PAE` extension. I just checked, the default repository doesn't contain any headers for that. I'll check if I can switch to a non-PAE version.

Comment: I need last info. Please show me `dnf search kernel-`.

Comment: [`dnf search kernel`](https://pastebin.com/sgi9nYiz).

Comment: About "headers you've installed": one interesting thing present. Your system run `4.15.10-300.fc27.i686+PAE` kernel, but there is no directory with kernel headers with that name. So you can solve this issue about two variants: 1) reboot system and choose in boot menu another version of kernel (without PAE); 2) execute `export KERN_VER=<path to headers>` and run installation. How get headers path? Do: `rpm -ql kernel-headers`(list all installed files) and get directory like `/usr/src/linux...`.

Comment: If you have some questions let me know. I have to go home and can answer to you in several hours.

Comment: Ok, I tried 1): Sadly, there are errors with the non-PAE errors, so I built the Additions (succesfully) and rebooted into the PAE-version again, sadly with the effect that the additions crashed. I then tried method 2) but am unable to change `KERN_VER` so that the script notices it. Sudo doesn't help. 

Would this even build the script differently from method 1)? If not, I don't even have to try, I guess the next step would be to try to trace down the error in the non-PAE version.

Comment: Sorry I came late night yesterday and go to sleep. I was very tired. I've just installed fedora27 and load in i686+PAE kernel. I want to say that answer from GracefulRestart is true. It's works. Sometimes is difficult to suggest, because I didn't have installed system. So, please set answer from GracefulRestart as solved.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it works. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a PAE kernel, any modules/extensions built in any other kernel will not work.  You must use the kernel you intend to use to build the modules/extensions.

You need the right kernel headers and development packages, which I believe is this: [kernel-PAE-devel-4.15.10-300.fc27.i686.rpm](https://fedora.pkgs.org/27/fedora-updates-i386/kernel-PAE-devel-4.15.10-300.fc27.i686.rpm.html)

Make sure that package is installed and then see if the guest tools can build properly.